# Single characters in JPA SELECT examples

Tags: sql, jpa

Why are there charactes like 'e' or 'c' in all simple JPA SELECT examples? What is their purpose, what are they replaced with?

```
TypedQuery<Professor> query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Employee e",
    Professor.class);
List<Professor> emps = query.getResultList();
```

or

```
Query q1 = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Country c");
TypedQuery<Country> q2 =
          em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Country c", Country.class);
```

Why not just a * instead of two 'c'? Especially the second 'c' irritates with  a normal SQL SELECT in mind:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

I understand setting params

```
TypedQuery<Country> query = em.createQuery(
    "SELECT c FROM Country c WHERE c.name = :name", Country.class);
return query.setParameter("name", name).getSingleResult();
```

but I never see where 'c' is defined. Is it just some sort of wildcard?

Comment: Think I got it now: It's an alias that we need 99% of the time anyway, therefore it is just part of the syntax. What it stands for is always givenout of context, e.g. the TypedQuery<Country>. When we query for (java) objects SELECT * is the only thing that makes sense, therefore it is just what a SELECT * looks like in JPA

Comment: . . I am not familiar with JPA.  But in other databases that support this syntax, `SELECT *` returns a bunch of columns, whereas `SELECT <alias>` returns a record/struct containing the columns.

Comment: I's just an alias. It is used as a shortcut, you can use a shorter version with alias: `SELECT e FROM employes e WHERE e.name='John'` instead of `SELECT employes FROM employes WHERE employes.name='John'`

Answer (score 0):

In JPA that's called "identification variable" (not alias).

From the JPA specification:

> **4.4.2 Identification Variables**
>
> An identification variable is a valid identifier declared in the FROM
>   clause of a query. All identification variables must be declared in
>   the FROM clause. Identification variables cannot be declared in other
>   clauses.
>
> An identification variable must not be a reserved identifier or have
>   the same name as any entity in the same persistence unit.
>
> Identification variables are case insensitive.
>
> An identification variable evaluates to a value of the type of the
>   expression used in declaring the variable. For example, consider the
>   previous query:
>
> SELECT DISTINCT o FROM Order o JOIN o.lineItems l JOIN l.product p
>   WHERE p.productType = 'office_supplies'